# Should I keep this function for finding nth prime or can this be optimized?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes

We have a coding homework related to prime and my friend wrote this code. Its long and I dont understand it that much and has `goto` which is I think frowned upon so I don't know. Can help decide if we should we keep it?

```
int getNth (int nth){
    vector<int> prime;
    int sievelmt = nth*10;
    int i,j;
    func:
    vector<int> sieve(sievelmt, -1);
    prime.push_back(2); if (nth == 1) return 2;
    prime.push_back(3); if (nth == 2) return 3;
    prime.push_back(5); if (nth == 3) return 5;
    for (i = 2; i <= sievelmt; i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0||i%3==0||i%5==0) continue;
        if (sieve[i] == -1)
        {
            prime.push_back(i); if (prime.size()==nth) return prime[prime.size()-1];
            for ( j = 1; i*j <= sievelmt; j++) sieve[i*j]=j;
        }
        else continue;
    }    
    sievelmt *= 10;
    sieve.clear(); prime.clear();
    goto func;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Well the label and the `goto` could easily be replaced by an infinite loop. Never use labels and `goto` as loops.

Comment: For this code how will i do that?

Comment: the first one to ask about code when it is unclear is the author. Did you ask your friend?

Comment: he says it about finding nth prime. we not sure if this code is good.

Comment: Well, that's subjective, but I personally find it a bit lame that he throws out all his prior intermediate results and starts over whenever it turns out his vector is too small.

Comment: The `prime` array is never used except as a very expensive counter, and to return the last thing pushed (which is always `i` at that point).

Comment: Replacing 10 with 30 means you never have to resize the sieve. `std::bitset` is a better choice than `vector<int>` (it's 32 or 64 times smaller).

Comment: Any ways to use the previous calculation without throwing them away? And yeah the prime array should be removed its just a expensive counter for nothing. Why 30 instead of 10? I'm looking into the bitset thing. I'm new to c++

Comment: @SodaFries Why 30 better than 10. Well in theory it is not better. We know that the n-th prime is approximatively n.ln(n), for ints of size 32 bits it may be sufficient to use factor 30.

Comment: I was thinking alot about the multiplier and saw the curve of nth prime and stuff. But i couldnt figure out so i didn't change the 10. Idk why but i tried like n * 10^log(n) and stuff just guessing. Anything that is better mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the algorithm is this line:

```
for ( j = 1; i*j <= sievelmt; j++) sieve[i*j]=j;
```

For a given `i` that fills locations of array `sieve` that are multiples of `i`, with the rank of the multiple. Imagine `i=7`, then `sieve[7]=1`, `sieve[14]=2`, `sieve[21]=3`, etc.

This is the base of Eratosthène's sieve, a very very old algorithm ([Eratosthène](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) was an ancient Greek scientist) to find primes. If you make `i` vary from 2 to some value, then this will mark every location whose index is not prime. At the end, every location not marked is then a prime. Let see:

- `i=2` `.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.`
- `i=3` `.112.2.435.4.75`, 3 is prime (first time location 3 has been visited)
- `i=4` `.111.2.235.3.75`
- `i=5` `.11112.232.3.73`, 5 is prime (first time location 5 has been visited)
- `i=6` `.11111.232.3.73`
- `i=7` `.111111232.3.23`, 7 is prime
- `i=8` `.111111132.3.23`
- `i=9` `.111111112.3.23`
- `i=10` `.111111111.3.23`
- `i=11` `.11111111113.23`, 11 is prime
- etc.

Why is there a `goto` here? Don't worry, there exists numerous dangerous usage of `goto`, but that one is not. If you don't feel ok with that one replace:

```
func:
...
goto func;
```

with:

```
while(1) {
...
}
```

So the *real* question is why there is some "infinite" loop other there?

This is because you are looking for the n-th prime, but you can't easily determine how long the array must be to be able to capture the n-th prime... So that implementation just tries with increasing sizes. The first time, algorithm hopes that the n-th prime will be in an array of size 10*n, if it is not sufficient, then the size is mutiplied by 10, again, and again, until the n-th prime will be in.

Could I optimize this?

Sure, there is some little tricks. First you can see that if a given `i` it is divisible by 2, 3 or 5, then it can't be prime. That has already been implemented:

```
if (i%2==0||i%3==0||i%5==0) continue;
```

Then you may say, ok if divisible by 7 or 11 or 13, etc (means by any other prime), it's the same! I will not tell you more, but of course you can transform that algorithm to determine if a given `i` is or not divisible by any prime less then `i` (maybe by storing slightly different values in the array).

Comment: Thanks alot. So every time i check if its divisible by prime number of calculations needed decrease by 1/prime right? So after maybe 7 or 13 will it be better than just running the loop? I could create a loop to test against all previous prime should i do that?

Comment: You don't have to test that in a loop. If it is divisible by a prime then is has already been viewed...(see?)